# Why this configuration revealed my directories and files before document root?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/example
```

When I open the website on my browser like www.example.com it is listing all the files under /var/www/example directory instead of a page!

But if I use `ServerAlias www.example.com` it works fine just wondering what could be the problem?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What exactly doesn't work? What exactly do you expect to happen and what does happen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Apache httpd receives a host name in the HTTP/1.1 `Host` header which no `VirtualHost` exists for or no `Host` header at all, it'll serve the first `VirtualHost` it encounters in its configuration.

`www.example.com` is currently not configured in your snippet, so Apache httpd will serve the default `VirtualHost` which probably has the `DocumentRoot` `/var/www/`.

If you want to know details you should read [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html).